# zsh: conda not found even after included in path and installed

Tags: python, anaconda

I was doing something & I messed up everything. Now if I type `conda` in terminal and it says zsh conda not found

Here's my .zshrc file

```
alias python='python3'

# added by Anaconda3 4.4.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/abhimanyuaryan/anaconda/bin:$PATH"export PATH="/usr/local/opt/opencv3/bin:$PATH"
```

I tried re-installing anaconda but it says it's already installed in my home directory consider upgrading anacoda and then installation fails

with a message that installer failed with an error contact manufacturer for assitance

Answer (score 0):

Removed anaconda completely and reinstalled anaconda fixed this problem

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in my **macOS Catalina**, tried everything but nothing went on work, at last I found the way how to git rid of this error, just follow few steps and you will get an amazing result.

**step one** - press command and space, and type users on the spotlight search, type users, you will see your computer name click on it and in the upper search bar for searching folder files of the finder, type anconda (your version) and delete the folder.

**step two** - download and install it back but be careful in the step of installation when your are installing it for yourself, rather go for the disk and click on the disk then click on the change location and add the location of (Users/computer name/ ) and then install it, it's all done!, try this command `conda --version` , if it works it means you are able to work with conda, check your python version as well: by the command  `python --version` .